# show that the conditions of LMVT are not satisfied in the interval $[a,b]$ but the conclusion of the theorem is true if and only if $b>1+\sqrt2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $a=-1$ and $b\geq1$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|},$ show that the conditions of Lagrange's mean value theorem are not satisfied in the interval $[a,b]$ but the conclusion of the theorem is true if and only if $b>1+\sqrt2$

---

It is obvious fro the graph that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$ is not continuous at $x=0$ and hence not differentiable at $x=0$.So the conditions of LMVT are not met in the interval $[a,b].$
Let there is a point $c\in[a,b]$ such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c),a<c<b$
But i am stuck here.I do not know how to find the derivative of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ and procced further to prove the given claim.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

*I do not know how to find the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}$*.

Notice that
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x},\quad x>0\\\\
-\frac{1}{x},\quad x<0
\end{align}\right.$$
and thus
$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{x^2},\quad x>0\\\\
\frac{1}{x^2},\quad x<0
\end{align}\right.$$